# Proving that the interior of a metric space is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

WTS: The interior of a metric space A is open.

Proof:

Let a $\in$ $int(A)$, we can find a  $\delta$ $>0$ : $N_{\delta}(a)$ $\subset A$, hence a is in some open neighborhood, so a $\in$ $N_{\delta}(a)$, for some $\delta$ $>0$. Hence $int(A) \subset  $ $\bigcup\limits_{a \in int(A)}N_{\delta}(a)$. But since every neighborhood is contained within the interior of A, it follows that $\bigcup\limits_{a \in int(A)}N_{\delta}(a)$ $\subset int(A)$, hence the two sets are equal. May someone tell me how to improve it, and what I can do to make it better, clearer and logical?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Your proof is concise and accurate.

Comment: Your notation ($\bigcup\limits_{a \in int(A)}N_{\delta}(a)$) suggests that $\delta$ is the same for all $a$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback!

Comment: Why is "every neighborhood contained in the interior of $A$"?  Obviously $N_{\frac 12}(\frac 14)\not \subset (0,1)$

Comment: The definition of an interior of a set A is the set of all x$\in$ such that the neighbourhood is contained in A. If the neighbourhood is contained within A, is it not the case that the neighbourhood is contained in the interior? @fleablood

Comment: Every neighbor hood selected was selected to be a neighborhood contained in $A$; not the interior of $A$.  So we know $N_{\delta_a} (a) \subset A$ but we don't know $N_{\delta_a}(a) \subset int A$

Comment: @fleablood I see what you mean.

Comment: I think that is precisely what you need to prove.  Consider a set that is not open.  $[0,1]$ and its interior, we'll take for granted that it is $(0,1)$ Now for for $a\in(0,1)$ we can find a $\delta$ so that $N_\delta (a) \in (0,1)$.  Do we know that $0 \not \in N_\delta(a)$?  Can we geeneralize that?

Comment: @topologicalmagician An important point to note: in several of your posts you are replacing the term '$A$ is a subset of a metric space' by '$A$ is a metric space'.  The interior of any metric space $X$ is $X$ itself so it is obviously open.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is perfectly fine.

Maybe an easier approach would be just to state that the interior of A is the union of all open sets contained in A, and any union of open sets is again open.

Comment: That depends on the definition of interior.

Answer (score 0):

If you know already that open (in the sense of being defined by $<r$) balls $N_r(a)$ are open (in the metric topology), your argument is fine, writing the interior as a union of open balls this way.

Otherwise maybe show that first as a lemma of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

For every $a\in A$  we have $a\in N_1(a)\subset A$ so $a\in N_1(a)\subset int (A)$ so every $a\in A$ belongs to $int(A).$

So $A\subset  int (A).$

And we also have $int (A)\subset A$.

So $A\subset int (A)\subset A,$ which implies $A=int(A).$